# Reset iPhone 5s (iOS 8.4) WITHOUT updating iOS

Tags: iphone

I own an old iPhone 5s. It hasn't been hooked up with a carrier for a year and a half. I wish to reset it to get all my personal data, contacts, etc. off and then give it to a new user. **I want the phone to continue using iOS 8.4**. I DO NOT want ios to update to a newer version when the new user connects the phone to a carrier.

**Q: If I reset the phone via Settings, will iOS 8.4 remain on the phone after reset?** And, if so, will it remain on the phone after a new carrier is set upfor the device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you reset from settings you’ll stay in your current version. You’re also fine to connect to a carrier, you will not be automatically updated. You may be prompted to perform a carrier settings update but that will not change your iOS version.